# Not able to get rid of Status Bar in my android app. Have tried all the suggested(working) solutions in SO

Tags: android

I have tried everything mentioned below but still not able to get rid of the Status Bar.

The LinearLayout in the layout xml has fill_parents for both vertical and horizontal attributes

Manifest :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Activity :

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);  
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

**EDIT :**

The solution works if I add the android theme(android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen") to application node rather than at the activity level in the manifest file. Why could it be so? what if I need this full screen behaviour for only one of the activities?

Comment: rid status bar it mean , you want to remove status bar right or else?

Comment: dont want to show it at all. I want my app to be full screen. It should not appear even when I touch the screen!

Comment: i think u had set this android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: i had use that ,i think it work fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this..

```
<activity android:name=".abc"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation"></activity>
```

Comment: To make it application wise configuration, you can place it in <application> manifest.

Comment: Not working still. Title goes but not the top status bar :(. I am using HTC Wildfire-S(2.3.5) for testing. That should not matter, right?

Comment: Is there anything like Z-index for the status bar bcoz I can see it covering a part of my UI at the top...?

Comment: have you test this on emulator and diff device?

Comment: test this in Both emulator and device then we can find out what is problem..after testing tell me , is it work or not?